# Variablegroups - Get Variable Groups not getting hidden password values

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Why can't I retrieve the variable in a library group that's a hidden password? When I try to access it it's blank.

I'm using [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-5.1) and the [Get Variable Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/get-variable-groups?view=azure-devops-server-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) action

```
$variableGroup.value.variables.hiddenPasswordVariable1.value
```